# Download Excel with pivot table IE appending [1] to file name

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, struts2

Currently I am face this issue.

when I am directly opening from IE with out saving , IE adding [1]/Version to file name

Example: Test.xlsx file in backend but when i am opening the file its renamed to Test[1].xlsx.And this is creating the issue.

Can any one suggest what I am doing wrong here.

```
//res.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
               //res.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
               //res.reset();
               //res.setHeader("Expires", "0");

      myDownloadTask{
              //res.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate,post-check=0, pre-check=0");
               //res.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
               //res.setContentType("application/force-download");
               //res.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
               res.setContentType("application/ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");
               res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

               fileName=EncodeFileName(fileName);

               res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName);
       }
```

Comment: Users usually don't care of extra numbers in downloaded file names. BTW in S2 use `stream` result to download file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a file with `Test.xlsx` already on your hard disk, this is why IE rename it to `Test[1].xlsx`.

I think you can not handle it, you can create a unique file name on the server every time, or gently prompt to user to make sure he does not have a file with same name on his hard disk !